# db connection deadlock

Tags: spring, ibatis, spring-3

We have a web application that has been running well for several years. The web application was using mysql, spring-1.2.6, and ibatis.

After replacing spring-1.2.6 with spring-3.2.0, we started to notice a problem that multiple concurrent requests to a particular page always hang for some reason.

jConsole shows the following for each concurrent thread:

```
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING on 
   org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch@b6b09e
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
   at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1104)
```

After investigation, we found that this problem has something to do with a resultMap that looks like the following. With spring-1.2.6, only one connection was needed for each thread regardless of the number of rows in the result set. However, with spring-3.2.0, N+1 connections (depending on the number of rows returned) are needed for each thread. Hence the deadlock. (We are using the default value (8) of maxActive property in our configuration.)

How can I fix it so that connections are reused in this case? Thanks.

```
<resultMap id="resultBlog" type="Blog">
    <id property="id" column="idBlog" />
    <result property="name" column="blogname" />
    <result property="url" column="blogurl" />
    <result property="author" column="idBlog" select="selectAuthor" />
</resultMap>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, this is iBatis (2.x), not MyBatis (3.x +)?
Also, are you using Spring TX management and / or {i|my}batis integration?

Comment: we are using ibatis-2.3.0.677 and are not using spring tx.